# is it allowed to write fb rating average in android app description?

Tags: android, google-play

After adapting a facebook game for android, I was wondering if I can say in the app description that the game has 4 stars on facebook.

One of the latest rules of Google Play listing is you cannot include user testimonials in description.

Though not exactly a testimonial, I don't know if a facebook average rating might be considered against the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Google Play bans and external reviews. If they allow facebook, why not allow a different website? (they are not parnters in any way). You can control the bias on those websites and so that information will not represnt 100% the true value of the app. They count on their Play's comment review system.

Comment: Thanks Mihai, do you think I can say in the description: the game had x thousand total users on Facebook? Or is that against the rules also ?

Comment: That I don't know exactly, but it's probably not allowed. Practically they don't allow you to influence the user with external numbers. The best thing you could do is to say that it's popular on facebook or something like that.

Comment: Ok, I've opted for something like "success on other platforms"